# Edited bitmap only saving drawn changes without original picture in shared storage and empty bitmap in internal storage

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, scoped-storage

I was adding a new feature to my drawing app project where users could open any picture from the phone gallery and draw on it. But I am having issues saving the new bitmap. Here are the details below :

My app has 3 activities :

- Main Activity as a menu,
- RecyclerView activity that acts as a gallery,
- Drawing activity where users draw

Up until recently whenever a user saved an image, it would create two copies of it. One private that would be stored in application's personal storage that is not available to phone's gallery to use but is displayed in applications own gallery activity, and one public picture in media which will be displayed in the phones gallery. My gallery class checks the internal folder of the application and lists all files in it to display, that is why I also save in private app directory too. Save image method has two sections that handles the scoped storage issues with api 28+ and <28 respectively.

Recently I added a feature where users can pick any picture from phone's gallery and edit it (both images that app created and those that it did not).It uses intent picker function.

Expected results are :

- Open a picture from the gallery in the drawing activity and draw on top of it
- Save edited version as a new image both privately in app's storage and a public shared copy in phones main gallery

Current issues :

- Image opens and is drawn upon without problems (both images made by the app and foreign pictures)
- Saving images causes the app to save an empty bitmap in phones private gallery and changes (edits drawn) in shared storage on the phone without actual image that was meant to be edited.

Here is the code :

From MainActivty, code that opens the images from phone's gallery in order to edit them.

```
    // checks permissions for reading external and scoped storage before opening image picker
    private void pickAnImage() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SDK >= Q , requesting permission");
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1000);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SDK < Q , requesting permission");
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1000);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission exists, starting pick intent");
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, IMAGE);
        }
    }

    // handles results from permissions and begins intent picker
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            Log.d(TAG, "result code good");
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Permission is granted, starting pick");
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, IMAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "While result code is good, permission was denied");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    
    // handles results from intent picker and feeds the image path to the drawing activity for image editing
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE && data != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Data from picked image is not null, creating uri and path");
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String picturePath = getPath(getApplicationContext(), selectedImageUri);
//            Log.d("Picture Path", picturePath);

            if (picturePath != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Path creating success, calling art activity");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ArtActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", picturePath);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Path was null");
                finish();
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Data seems to be null, aborting");
        }
    }

    // obtains the path from the picked image
    private static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(proj[0]);
                result = cursor.getString(column_index);
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get image path , result is null or permission problem ?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            result = "Not found";
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Below are methods that handle bitmap editing process :

```
// Inside initialization method that sets up paint and bitmap objects before drawing
 if (bitmap != null) {
        // if bitmap object is not null it means that we are feeding existing bitmap to be edited, therefore we just scale it to screen size before giving it to canvas
        loadedBitmap = scale(bitmap, width, height);
    } else {
        // bitmap fed to this method is null therefore it means we are not editing existing picture so we create a new object to draw on
        this.bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    }
```

Inside onDraw method that handles drawing as it happens :

```
if (loadedBitmap != null) {
            // loadedBitmap not being null means we are editing existing image from above, we previously scaled it so now we feed it to the canvas for editing
            canvas.drawBitmap(loadedBitmap, 0, 0, paintLine);
            canvas.clipRect(0, 0, loadedBitmap.getWidth(), loadedBitmap.getHeight());
        } else {
            // we are not editing an image so we draw new empty bitmap to use
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, tPaintline);
        }
```

And finally, here is the infamous save image method that is the root of current problems :

```
@SuppressLint("WrongThread") // not sure what to do otherwise about this lint
public void saveImage() throws IOException {

    //create a filename and canvas
    String filename = "appName" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    Canvas canvas;

    // loadedBitmap is the edited one, bitmap is a new one if we did not edit anything
    if(loadedBitmap != null){
        canvas = new Canvas(loadedBitmap);
    } else{
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }

    // save image handle for newer api that has scoped storage and updated code
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            // feed all the data to content values
            OutputStream fos;
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename + ".jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            
            
            Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
            draw(canvas);
            
            // compress correct bitmap, loaded is edited, bitmap is new art
            if(loadedBitmap != null){
                loadedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            }else{
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            }

            Objects.requireNonNull(fos).close();
            imageSaved = true;

    } else {

        // for api older then 28 before scoped storage
        // create app directory and a new image file
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pathString = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).toString();
        File myPath = new File(directory, filename + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
   
        // check permissions
        try {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                draw(canvas);
                
                // save edited or new bitmap to private internal storage
                if(loadedBitmap != null){
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), loadedBitmap, filename, "made with appName");
                }else{
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, filename, "made with appName");
                }
                
                // now also add a copy to shared storage so it will show up in phone's gallery
                addImageToGallery(myPath.getPath(), context);
                imageSaved = true;

            }else{
                // request permissions if not available
                requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                        new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                        100);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Save image to gallery method used above :

```
    // for old api <28, it adds the image to shared storage and phone's gallery
    public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

That is all, if anyone knows bitmap, canvas and permissions (old and new) feel free to help. I am sure tha changes I need are small. Check the current issues above in order to know what to look for.